# Auto-rotate only for YouTube app, disabled otherwise

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, automation, youtube, auto-rotation

I find auto-rotate really annoying so I generally have it turned off.

Unfortunately, when I'm playing a YouTube video, it's equally annoying when I try to tilt the screen and then remember I have it turned off  :)

I would like a way to have auto-rotate working as usual when a YouTube video is playing, otherwise disabled.

Is that possible? I would like it all handled automatically, I'm not really interested in apps or widgets where I have to toggle a setting manually.

P.S. My phone is a Galaxy Nexus.

Comment: I don't know what ROM you're using but YouTube actually ignores my auto-rotate setting regardless of it being on or off. YouTube still goes to landscape mode when I tilt my phone whilst watching a video even if I have auto-rotate set to off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a system setting, so the app [Smart Rotator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.xdevelop.rotator_t) is probably the closest thing you can get, but yes, in the beginning, you have to set everything up yourself.

Comment: This looks promising, I'll give it a shot...

Comment: The link doesn't work anymore, but there is another amazing app that does this. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.snowlife01.android.rotationcontrol

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively, my default recommendation for cases like this: [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm). Use a profile like this (abstract):

**Condition:** App (select "Youtube", and optionally other apps you would like to have autorotate turned on)

**Task:** Display->Display Rotation: Set On

This way, whenever one of the selected apps runs in foreground, autorotate is turned on -- and as soon as that condition is no longer met, autorotate is turned to whatever it was set to before. To make sure to have it turned off afterwards, you can add a so called "exit task":

**Exit:** Display->Display Rotation: Set Off

Hm, looks like currently I answer every 2nd question with "Tasker"...

Comment: Tasker is certainly a Swiss Army knife. It's well worth using.

Comment: You don't actually need the exit action, as Tasker restores settings (like display rotation) when the condition stops being true. Every once and a while it gets left on (e.g., if the phone dies with YouTube open), you can fix that with a task to disable on screen on.

Comment: Yup, derobert's comment is correct. I just tried it before reading this answer, and I didn't have to add exit task to toggle the auto-rotation back.

Comment: @AndrewT. not necessarily, no. By default, *Tasker* automatically reverts to the previous state. So without the Exit-Task, if auto-rotation already was on, it would not be turned off afterwards. If that's what you want, ommit the Exit-Task. If you however definitely want it turned-off afterwards, no matter what: then you will need the Exit-Task.